# CSS Limited Border Size

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a border underneath and on the right side of each field to separate them and make it match the rest of my website. I've tried messing with the padding and margin but that screws up the centering. My goal is to have a border underneath and on the right side of each field to separate them and make it match the rest of my website

PS. Im using ruby on rials and the devise gem for login pages with bootstrap installed if that affects anything

```
<center>
  <div class = "jumbotron-main">
    <center>
      <h2>Log In</h2>

      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <div class="field" "box">
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
          <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
        </div>

        <div class="field" "box">
          <%= f.label :password %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
        </div>

        <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
            <%= f.label :remember_me %>
          </div>
        <% end -%>
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-bg-danger">
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</center>

<style>
  h2{
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding-top: 12px;
  }

  .field{
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  }

  .jumbotron-main{
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: #4F4F4F;
    width: 60%;
    color: black;
    height: 80% !important;
  }

  .jumbotron{
    margin-top: 10%;
    background-color: #EB5757;
    width: 400px;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
  }

  #user_username{
  background-color: #999999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
}

  #user_email{
  background-color: #999999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
  #user_password{
  background-color: #999999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
}

  #user_password_confirmation{
  background-color: #999999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use border-right and border-bottom?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sample">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#sample{
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: I may not have my goal clear enough, I tried that but it gives the border to the entire length, I want to have the border only travel a small length

Comment: Do you want a border only on the corner of the cell? Maybe you could share a basic drawing of what you want to achieve?

Comment: As an example, says I have a rectangle with a width of 10 and a height of 8. I want a border that goes say 8 from right to left and a height of 10

Comment: Is this somewhat what your looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/v8L9gxtn/7/

Comment: Yes, something like this will work with a few changes. Thanks

Comment: Perfect. You can mess around with the percentage maybe. If you want pure line without gradient, you can set both at 70% for example and it will do the trick.